# How can you remove whitespaces accidentally entered by a user when entering setting values (Userdefaults)

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I'm using Swift5's UserDefaults to store text key pair preferences. What some users of my app have been doing is accidentally adding a space before or after the string which is then causing problems.

Please can someone advise me on how I can intercept the submitted text string entered in settings and remove whitespaces before it is saved?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a [example] to illustrate the issue?

Comment: If they're accidentally surrounding the string in whitespace, you could trim it. `let trimmedString = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)`

Comment: I hope my answer has solved your question. Please consider to accept my answer if it helped you and other SO users may benefit from that.

Answer (score 2):

Before your user-entered `String` gets saved, do this to trim all leading and trailing whitespaces:

```swift
let rawStr = " YOUR USER ENTERED STRING  "
let trimmedStr = rawStr.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

// Save `trimmedStr` into UserDefaults here
```

If you also want to trim newlines, use `.whitespacesAndNewlines` instead of `.whitespaces`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var text = "Dummy Text   "

print(text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))

//Output --> DummyText
```

For newline **whitespacesAndNewlines**